# Why can I not update the foreign key of an object in a 1:1 association?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have two models, User and Profile.
A User has_one Profile and a Profile belongs_to User.
Correspondingly, the Profile model has a `user_id` attribute.

The association works:

```
p = Profile.first
=> #<Profile id: 1, name: "Jack", ... , user_id: 1>
u = User.first
=> #<User id: 1, email: "jack@example.com", ... >
u.profile.id
=> 1
p.user.id
=> 1
p.user == u
=> true
u.profile == p
=> true
```

I can set the `user_id` field on a Profile directly:

```
p.user_id = 2
=> 2
p.save!
=> true
p.user_id
=> 2
```

But why can I not set the `user_id` like this:

```
u.profile.user_id = 2
=> 2
u.profile.save!
=> 2
u.profile.user_id
=> 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must refresh `u.profile` object. Try this:

```
u.profile.user_id = 2
=> 2
u.profile.save!
=> 2
u.profile.reload.user_id
=> 2
```

This is because `original` profile object is still loaded on memory in `u`.

Hope this help :)